# Exit current browser (return one level)

Tags: r

Sometimes you throw multiple `browser`s into a function to debug.  I know you can exit the whole shebang with `Q` but what if you want to exit the second browser (see below's code) and return to the first level of browser?  I've heard type `c` but that doesn't exit the second level `browser`.

```
FUN <- function() {
browser()                      #first one
    lapply(1:10, function(x) {
browser()                      #second one
        return(x)
    })
}

FUN()
```

Comment: I add `qwer` (or something else) right after the second browser. I then manually flip through code and when I want to exit the second browser, I just press `c`. It throws an error that object `qwer` does not exist, but I'm already out, have my pants on and on my way home. :)

Comment: This is actually genius and it's like tricking R.  flodel gives the responsible approach but this is likely what I'll do.  I think you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with Josh and would like to suggest these two alternatives to your current code:

1) `debugonce`: If we call `foo` your inner function, then `debugonce(foo)` will launch the debugger only the first time that `foo` is called, when `x==1`.

```
FUN <- function() {
  browser()
  foo <- function(x)return(x)
  debugonce(foo)
  lapply(1:10, foo)
}
```

2) `debug` and `undebug`. After you run `debug(foo)`, the debugger will be launched every time `foo` is called, and until you run `undebug(foo)`:

```
FUN <- function() {
  browser()
  foo <- function(x)return(x)
  debug(foo)
  lapply(1:10, foo)
}
```

When you want to stop debugging `foo`, type `undebug(foo)` before hitting `c` and it will take you back to the first level browser.

Comment: Very thorough and thoughtful answer.  Didn't know about these functions.  Thank you. +1

Comment: +1 There's also `browserSetDebug`, which lets you move up the call stack during a `browser` session. However, it doesn't seem to work right when the function launching the `browser` session is called from within `lapply`.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what the `condition` argument is for. At first I thought it might be like the `expr` argument to `browser`, determining whether or not the browser's invoked, but it's not...

Comment: Same here, @MatthewPlourde, the `condition` option is not what I thought it was, so I removed my mention of it.

Answer (score 10):

Typing `c` *does* exit the current browser context.

Your code, though, executes one "first level" and 10 distinct "second-level" browser calls during its execution. As a result, when you exit *one* second-level browser, you're almost immediately thrown into the *next* one, so it may appear that typing `c` doesn't work.

Type `c <RETURN>` 11 times to confirm that this is what's happening.

```
> FUN()
Called from: FUN()
Browse[1]> c
Called from: FUN(1:10[[1L]], ...)
Browse[1]> c
Called from: FUN(1:10[[2L]], ...)
Browse[1]> c
Called from: FUN(1:10[[3L]], ...)
Browse[1]> c
Called from: FUN(1:10[[4L]], ...)
Browse[1]> c
Called from: FUN(1:10[[5L]], ...)
Browse[1]> c
Called from: FUN(1:10[[6L]], ...)
Browse[1]> c
Called from: FUN(1:10[[7L]], ...)
Browse[1]> c
Called from: FUN(1:10[[8L]], ...)
Browse[1]> c
Called from: FUN(1:10[[9L]], ...)
Browse[1]> c
Called from: FUN(1:10[[10L]], ...)
Browse[1]> c
```

Answer (score 5):

I add `qwer` (or some other object that does not exist) right after the second browser. I then manually flip through code and when I want to exit the second browser, I just press `c`. It throws an error that object does not exist. You will be thrown back to the first browser call.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta -- I don't understand this trick, and wish I did. Where does the qwer go, and how does it allow you to escape the sequence of inside-the-loop browser calls when and only when you'd like to?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, I used: `lapply(seq(100), function(i) {browser(); quer})`  It will _not_ allow you to get through more than one iteration (if calling in an iterative context, of course). But it will kick you back just a single context level

Answer (score 0):

run undebug(yourFunction)
this will terminate debugging but still remain at the browser prompt
then type c and  (maybe a couple times) to come back to the regular command prompt