# nested browser calls -- exiting only a single context

Tags: r, debugging

### UPDATE:

I personally marked this question as a duplicate since this question appears to be nearly identical to what @TylerRinker's. However, **I would still consider this specific question *unanswered***. While I like `debug/debugonce` those are different (albeit very useful) tools and I remain curious as to how to control `browser` contexts.

## **________________________________________________________________**

#### Original Question:

When debugging, it's easy and often helpful to step into a `browser` context from within another `browser` context. When the nested level is called from an iterative loop, exiting back to the previous context requires stepping through each iteration. 
Quitting via `Q` exits from *all* `browser` contexts.

#### The Question is:

**Is there a way to specify which context to exit to without needing to manually proceed through all iterations at the lower context?**

In the example below, that would mean going back to `Browse [1]` without having to hit `c` 100 times

The two I use are either to
(1) modify the number of iterations or
(2) use `Q`, call my original function again, then walk forward to where I previously was.
Neither constitutes "great" or event "good."

---

Example:

```
outerFunc <- function() { 
  # < ... cropped .. >
  browser()
  # < ... cropped .. >
}

outerFunc()
lapply(seq(100), function(i) browser(text=paste("i is #", i)))
```

#### this is the walk through

```
> outerFunc()
Called from: outerFunc()
Browse[1]> lapply(seq(100), browser)
Called from: lapply(seq(100), browser)
Browse[2]> c
Called from: lapply(seq(100), browser)
Browse[2]> c
Called from: lapply(seq(100), browser)
Browse[2]> c
Called from: lapply(seq(100), browser)
Browse[2]> Q    # <~~~~~~  `Q` quits all contexts
>
```

Comment: Perhaps see [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13663043/1478381)?

Answer (score 6):

Here is one maybe slightly hacky idea that takes advantage of `browser()`'s `expr=` argument to allow you to turn off browsing within the loop at any time.

```
outerFunc <- function() { 
  # < ... cropped .. >
  BROWSE <- TRUE
  browser()
  # < ... cropped .. >
}

outerFunc()
lapply(seq(100), function(i) browser(text=paste("i is #", i),
       expr=BROWSE))

Called from: FUN(1:100[[1L]], ...)
Browse[2]> 
Called from: FUN(1:100[[2L]], ...)
Browse[2]> 
Called from: FUN(1:100[[3L]], ...)
Browse[2]> 
Called from: FUN(1:100[[4L]], ...)
Browse[2]> 
Called from: FUN(1:100[[5L]], ...)
Browse[2]> BROWSE <<- FALSE        ## From here on, browser() won't be triggered
Browse[2]> 
[... many snipped lines ...]
Browse[1]>                         ## so that you're returned to next level
                                   ## up without further interruption
```

Comment: I like it!!!  +11.  I often use a `debug=FALSE` argument in my functions, with `browser(expr=debug)` kept in the code I know I'll be modifying often. It had not occurred to me to use this strategy.  great tip, thank you Josh

Comment: My code is littered with browser(expr=isTRUE(getOption("MyDEBUG"))). which was eneabled by option(MyDEBUG=TRUE) but I stopped using it since it started being to inter connected and cause chains of browsers being called. The suggestions already mentioned as most likely better options.