# Automate Chi-square across columns

Tags: r, chi-squared

I would like to use Chi-square for testing set of data. How to do it, using loop for or sapply.

This is a set of sample data:

```
n<-40
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(v1.1=sample(c('0','1'),n,replace=T),v1.2=sample(c('0','1'),n,replace=T),v1.3=sample(c('0','1'),n,replace=T),v1.4=sample(c('0','1'),n,replace=T),v1.5=sample(c('0','1'),n,replace=T),m1=sample(c('1','2'),n,replace=T))
```

I would like to test all variables named v1.x with variable m1. That's all.

I want **to avoid** such a situtation:

```
chisq.test(table(data$v1.1,data$m1))
chisq.test(table(data$v1.2,data$m1))
chisq.test(table(data$v1.3,data$m1))
chisq.test(table(data$v1.4,data$m1))
chisq.test(table(data$v1.5,data$m1))
```

I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225694/automate-chi-square-across-categories-and-columns), but for me and for now it's too difficult.

Comment: Have a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7382039/707145).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `lapply` to loop through the variables.

```
myTests <- lapply(data[-length(data)], function(x) chisq.test(table(x, data$m1)))
```

This returns a named list, with the changin variable as the name of each list item.

```
names(myTests)
[1] "v1.1" "v1.2" "v1.3" "v1.4" "v1.5"
```

Then access each with `myTests[[1]]` or `myTests[["v1.1"]]`. These return

```
    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  table(x, data$m1)
X-squared = 0, df = 1, p-value = 1
```

Then, to pull out components from the individual tests, use `names(myTests[[1]]` and `str(myTests[[1]])` to inspect the contents. `myTests[[1]]$p.value`, for example, will pull out the p.value from the first test and `unlist(sapply(myTests, "[", "p.value"))` will return a named vector with p-values from all of the tests.